# What does "a friend more than" mean?

Tags: meaning

I don't understand exactly what the sentence below means

> "I really do feel like she's a friend more than".

Does it mean "I feel like she's something more important than a friend" or "I feel like she's a friend more than anything" ?

I'm not familiar with a blank behind "more than". Which one is correct?

Comment: There must be a problem with the quotation, you can't end a sentence that way. "more than"  is used in comparisons, you have to have two things to compare.

Comment: It's not grammatical as it is. Please say where you found it.

Comment: I found that sentence in English Podcast transcript. they handle everyday conversations in their podcast.

Comment: You need to provide the source, the name of the podcast and a link IN the question. I agree that the line quoted  is a fragment sentence because it's missing the complement object.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the sentence is like this:

> "I really do feel like she's a friend more than a ...."

If the sentence is like that then the guy who's saying this probably means that  he is feeling her(the girl in the sentence) to be a friend rather than a (lover or girlfriend?).

Comment: thanks i think you are right. appreciate it.